# Loss of Dimension with Orthogonal Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I am working on trying to prove this claim:

Consider a nonzero vector v in Rn. What is the dimension of the space of all vectors in Rn that are perpendicular to v?

I think I intuitively understand it. Through orthogonal projection, one dimension collapses, resulting in a dimension of n-1. But, what would a more rigorous proof of this look like? Or is that explanation sufficient?

Comment: I think that's sufficient. If you need more, think of the equation defining the set of vectors perpendicular to $v$ and calculate the dimension of the solution space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, consider the linear map $\varphi_v \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\varphi_v(w) = \left< v, w \right>$. The kernel of $\varphi$ is precisely the subspace of vectors that are orthogonal to $v$. By the rank-nullity theorem,

$$ \dim \ker \varphi_v + \dim \mathrm{im} \varphi_v = n $$

and since $\varphi_v(v) = \left< v, v \right> \neq 0$, we have $\dim \mathrm{im} \varphi_v = 1$ and so $\dim \ker \varphi_v = n - 1$.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know that $v$ can be completed to an orthogonal basis $v_1 = v, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then clearly $v_i$ for $2 \leq i \leq n$ are orthogonal (and thus, linearly independent) vectors that are perpendicular to $v_1$ and so the dimension of the space of vectors perpendicular to $v_1$ is at least $n - 1$ and it clearly cannot be $n$ dimensional.